# What happens at control invoke function?

Tags: c#, multithreading

A question about form controls invoke function.
Control1  is created on thread1. 
If you want to update something in Control1 from thread2
you must do something like:

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string txt);  

void setText(string txt)  
{  
  if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)  
  {  
     SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(setText);  
     this.Invoke(d, new object[] { txt });  
  }  
  else  
  {   
     // this will run on thread1 even when called from thread2
     this.textBox1.AppendText(msg);  
  }  
}`
```

What happens behind the scenes here?

This invoke behaves different from a normal object invoke.
When you want to call a function in an object on a specific thread, then 
that thread must be waiting on some queue of delegates, and execute
the incoming delegates.

Is it correct that the windows forms control invoke function 
is completely different from the standard object invoke
function?

Comment: Good answer is e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703698/invokedelegate).

Answer (score 1):

To prevent thread issues, many Windows Forms operations have to happen on the UI thread. `Invoke` provides an easy way of accomplishing this without explicit thread management.

If you are curious about the internal workings, I would download a decompile tool (I believe Telerik JustDecompile is free) and look at `System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke` in the `System.Windows.Forms` DLL in the GAC.

BTW, it looks like it loads a reference to the UI thread and invokes your code in its environment.